# Match regex pattern only in filename.extension

Tags: linux, search, regex, find, gnu

I need to use `find` to locate a file matching a regex pattern in `filename.extension` instead of the default, which matches `/path/to/filename.extension`.

For instance:

```
/folder
  |--a-love-song.ogg
  |--a-jazz-song.ogg
  +--love-songs
       +--a-blues-song.ogg
```

And I want to find, in `/folder` and it's sub-directories, files with `.*love.*` in the filename:

```
debian@debian:~$ find folder -regex ".*love.*"
folder/a-love-song.ogg
folder/love-songs                   # Shouldn't be returned
folder/love-songs/a-blues-song.ogg  # Shouldn't be returned
```

I read the man page and realize there is the option `-name`, which searches only the filename, but it does not seem to allow regex, and `-name -regex` does not work.

I tried using regex to ignore the path:

```
debian@debian:~$ find folder -regex "\/.*love.*$"
```

But it didn't return anything. Of course `ls | grep` would work, but it doesn't return the path to the file, which I need in order to know where the file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that `ls` with `grep` would work if you got the full path to the file, how about `find` and `grep`? Because `grep` returns a line if a match is found anywhere in that line, your regex can match something that lacks `/`s before the filename and still contains your search string.

```
$ find folder | grep -i '[^/]*love[^/]*\.[a-z0-9]*'
```

That seems to work for me. The extension match can be reduced if you know all of your extensions lack numbers or if you know all of the files you want to match have a specific extension.

---

### Example usage

```
$ find folder
folder
folder/a-love-song.ogg
folder/love-songs
folder/love-songs/a-blues-song.ogg
folder/love-songs/another-love-song.ogg
$ find folder | grep -i '[^/]*love[^/]*\.[a-z0-9]*'
folder/a-love-song.ogg
folder/love-songs/another-love-song.ogg
```

---

### Attempted explanation of regex

- `[^/]*`: Matches any number of characters that are not `/`
- `love[^/]*`: Matches the string `love` and then any number of characters that are not `/`
- `\.[a-z0-9]*`: Matches a `.` and then any number of letters or digits

Put together, `[^/]*love[^/]*\.[a-z0-9]*` matches with as many non-`/` characters on either side of `love` with an extension tacked onto the end. Given the string `a/love/path/love-file.ogg` the above regex only matches `love-file.ogg`. If a leaf-folder contains `love`, for example: `a/path/love-leaf`, it does not match because `love-leaf` contains no `.` followed by letters or numbers.

Comment: Neat. Do you mind explaining what sorcery you did there? I mean, the regex part.

Comment: @Alex I can try! If you're still confused, I recommend http://regexpal.com/. It is a great resource to visualize regular expressions and what they match.

Answer (score 0):

```
find dir -regex '.*/[^/]*love[^/]*$'
```

Comment: That did not returned anything (yes I replaced dir with the directory).

Comment: Fixed the regex.

Comment: @grawity This still returns `dir/love-songs` (or any leaf directory with `love` in it). I'm not sure if it is possible to what @Alex wishes with just `find` alone.